# аналог функции шифрования php по ключу на js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

есть у меня 2 функции шифровки и дешифровки по указанному ключу на php:

```
function code_passw($text,$key) {
$td = mcrypt_module_open ("tripledes", '', 'cfb', '');
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size ($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
if (mcrypt_generic_init ($td, $key, $iv) != -1) 
    {
    $enc_text=base64_encode(mcrypt_generic ($td,$iv.$text));
    mcrypt_generic_deinit ($td);
    mcrypt_module_close ($td);
    return $enc_text;
    }
 }

function decode_passw($text,$key) {
$td = mcrypt_module_open ("tripledes", '', 'cfb', '');
$iv_size = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size ($td);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size ($td), MCRYPT_RAND);     
if (mcrypt_generic_init ($td, $key, $iv) != -1) {
        $decode_text = substr(mdecrypt_generic ($td, base64_decode($text)),$iv_size);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit ($td);
        mcrypt_module_close ($td);
        return $decode_text;
}
}
```

они хороши для простенького шифрования не требуют настройки ssl и каких то подключенных модулей.
Вопрос можно ли их перевести в js в плане того что бы я мог зашифровать\расшифровать на php и потом так же зашифровать\расшифровать на js 
есть ли в этом смысл? и сложно ли это, то что я нагуглил сам требует подключения какого то гигантского массива js билиотке

есть [на гитхабе js-mcrypt](https://github.com/tugrul/node-mcrypt) но через npm не качается и файлы странного формата хотя по описанию то что надо